# Paypal - How to Decreasing Recurring Payment Profile Amount

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-nvp, paypal-soap

Is it possible to decrease the recurring payment amount/rate using NVP API Operation for a recurring payment profile created using Express Checkout ?

I read here, merchant can increase the amount by 20% of the original amount every 180 days from the profile started date. However, it does not mention about decreasing the amount.

I am using UpdateRecurringPaymentsProfile it changes the SubscriberName but does not make any effect on amount. Explain if any one have any idea?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

According to PayPal NVP API 'UpdateRecurringPaymentsProfile' command (addmitedly confusing) [documentation](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/merchant/UpdateRecurringPaymentsProfile_API_Operation_NVP/), you need to pass the required 'METHOD', 'PROFILEID', 'AMT' and 'CURRENCYCODE' parameters.

In production, I have managed to reduce the amount of a subscription's recurring payments from 2.00€ to 1.35€ by using this set of parameters:

```
{
  :METHOD => "UpdateRecurringPaymentsProfile",
  :PROFILEID => profile_id, # something like "I-XXXU1WSJ6J11"
  :AMT => "19.95",
  :CURRENCYCODE => "EUR"
}
```

Key is passing not only the new amount, but also the currency. And it seems that reduction in amount is not subject to the 20% change limitation that increasing is subject to.